# Consulta sobre Angular y Html

Tags: php, html5, angular, google-analytics

Buenas tardes amigos necesito absolver mi duda me dejaron una plantilla y al ver el código me encontré con la sorpresa que no esta en HTML me parece que esta en Angular díganme deseo pasarla a HTML nuevamente se puede hacer ello hay alguna aplicación para realizarlo?. Líneas abajo pongo el código, agradeceré su apoyo.

```
 <!doctype html><html ng-app="sbAdmin2"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>sbAdmin2</title><meta name="description" content=""><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor-f67f68be.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-066834dd.css"></head><body><!--[if lt IE 10]>
 <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
 <![endif]--><div ui-view=""></div><script>
      (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
      function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
      e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
      ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
    </script><script src="scripts/vendor-984ea253.js"></script><script src="scripts/app-701b2d2f.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: No. Deben darte el código fuente del proyecto no la versión compilada.

Comment: desgraciadamente no me facilitaron esa version solo me dieron la que muestro por ello quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de revertir.

Comment: No. No se puede revertir.